# Mac OS only 4 out of 8 cores being utilized

Tags: multithreading, macos, cpu-usage

I have a very cpu-intensive program that I run on my Mac OS. It doesn't have any blocking IO, but just computing matrix multiplications.

I noticed that it only see 4 out of 8 cores of my macbook pro being used, based on the histogram below. any idea why?

[Mac OS CPU Utilization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHJSK.png)

[Mac Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYvEn.png)

[8 logic core 100% utilization by using spawning 8 processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkmc0.png)

Comment: One obvious explanation would be that the program is only launching 4 CPU-intensive threads -- a given thread can only use one core at a time.

Comment: Matrix multiplications may also be performed on the GPU, which will not directly appear as CPU utilization. (It depends on the software whether this is true or not, and whether the CPU is also involved in coordination). As Jeremy hints, you don't get parallelization for free inside a program. The program must intentionally make use of the available resources.

Comment: Does your macbook have 8 cores or 4 cores and hyperthreading?

Comment: @Willeke, interesting, my Mac does only have 4 physical cores, but 8 logic ones due to hyperthreading. Can all the logic cores be utilized to 100% simultaneously?

I have entered this command `yes > /dev/null &` 8 times and am able to see 100% utilization on all 8 logic cores. (screenshot add in the question above)

any thoughts on how to utiliize all logic cores?